# My Test Navigator copies some test cases from one test class to another

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

[image]

In this case my method `testDidSelectLocation()` should be in `DBLocationsViewControllerTests`. For some reason this is copied into another classes, marked with violet icon, and trying to pass a whole test. That additional tests, sometimes do not pass the tests. It is fixed only when I mark it as disabled. How to remove them?

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem after removing some of the tests which I don't need.
Following steps solved my problem:

1.)Quit Xcode

2.)Open your scheme file in a text editor(Don't use Xcode UI to edit scheme, you have to manually open from your local storage, I found it under: xxxxx.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/xxxx-tests.xcscheme)

3.)Delete all the skipped tests under `<SkippedTests>...</SkippedTests>`

4.)Delete Derived data folder under Developer/Xcode

5.)Restart Xcode